# Can't insert new Entity Framework entity using ".Add()"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, silverlight

I am trying save a new `Person` to the database.  My code compiles just fine but when I run it I get an error at at the `.Add()`.

The error says,
"`This EntitySet of Type 'Diavik.DataAccess.Person' does not support the 'Add' operation.`"

This is a SilverLight application and this file is the `App.xaml.cs`.

Here is my code:

```
private void OnGetPerson_Completed(LoadOperation<Person> operation)
{
    Person person = operation.Entities.SingleOrDefault();

    if (person == null)
    {
        person = new Person()
        {
            FirstName = WebContext.Current.User.FirstName,
            LastName = WebContext.Current.User.LastName,
            IlluminatorLogin = WebContext.Current.User.Name
        };

        Context.Persons.Add(person);
    }

    Context.SubmitChanges(submitOp =>
    {
        // Some Stuff
    }, null);
}
```

Thank you for your help,

Aaron

Comment: How is your domain service looks like? Do you have an `[Insert]` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have a method in your Domain Service marked as an `[Insert]` method. It must be `public`, `void`, and take only one parameter (the `Person` object).

Something like this:

```
[Insert]
public void InsertPerson(Person p)
{
    ObjectContext.Persons.AddObject(p);
}
```

This code may not be exactly what you need because I don't know what your domain service looks like, but you get the general idea.

You don't actually need to call this service method directly, the RIA Services link handles the translation between this method and when you call `Persons.Add()` on the client side. It just has to exist, that's all.

Comment: Ahh! I did `Attach` by mistake. Stupid 5 year old project.